# Listview save to a txt file

Tags: c#, listview

I need that all data which I can see now in Find_ list View are online added to C:\Users\Public\WattLOG.txt file
Then I Will Access to this file with another program and read all events.
When there comes new line, I need to store it immediately in file.

```
        private void Find_listView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Search_listView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate [mcve] with emphasis on minimality

Comment: Please show only code that is important for your question.